# is there any google/aws services to move data from google store to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-2.0

In my usecase all google related app and ads data generation is going to store in google store.but my processing engine runs on Spark on AWS cloud.
can some one please help how i can move this GS data S3 to process.

Thank You in advance

Comment: If you were moving data from S3 to Google, Google has a "Google Cloud Transfer Service" which does just that. Not sure about the opposite.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough the destination is always a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: You could probably use GCS object change notifications to notify an app running on Google Cloud or in AWS and that app could transfer the file. Or take a look at Google Cloud Functions and write a small script that would automatically copy to S3 any new objects placed in your GCS bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the google storage lib on your spark classpath, your EMR code just uses gs:// references for remote access for gcs cloud data. With the right credentials it's accessible from anywhere, including EMR.

You will run up bills though, and have to wait for slower reads and writes.